# Mysqli add numeric value with concat?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, mysqli, concatenation

I need to update a the employee hours column with the current numeric value that is already existed in the database.

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE `".MYDATABASE."`.`".MYTABLE."` 
SET employeeHours='".$employeeHours."' 
WHERE sessionID='".session_id()."'");
```

This like is working properly but needless to say that it's overwriting the old value.

My goal is to add the current `$employeeHours` to the existed value in the database.

I assume that it's done with `concat` but I'm not sure about the syntax.

Small tweak needed here...

Comment: `SET employeeHours = employeeHours + '".$employeeHours."'`

Comment: Really? So simple? :O

Comment: Yes, you take the current employeeHours + $employeeHours and the result is stored. `CONCAT` is used to build up a string value, combining several columns/text/whatever into 1 column. It also used to build up dynamic SQL syntaxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't believe that it would be so ridiculously simple :

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE `".MYDATABASE."`.`".MYTABLE."` SET employeeHours = employeeHours + '".$employeeHours."' WHERE sessionID='".session_id()."'");
```

Thank you @castis!